Is there an R-function to interpolate contours which fits a shapefile?
I am plotting contour maps using R. The program is able to plot the contours but it is not able to interpolate the plot to fit and fill the provided shapefile. Is there a specific function in R which can help to generate a proper contour map? The program is below. The image I obtained is also attached.
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(ggspatial)
library(dplyr) 

data_points <- read.csv("data_points.csv")
mauritius_shape <- st_read("mus_admbnda_adm0_2020_v2.shp")
data_points <- data_points %>%
rename(lon = longitude, lat = latitude)
lon_min <- 57.3
lon_max <- 57.8
lat_min <- -20.5
lat_max <- -19.95
data_points_filtered <- data_points %>% 
filter(lon >= lon_min & lon <= lon_max & lat >= lat_min & lat <= lat_max)
data_points_filtered <- data_points %>%
filter(lon >= lon_min & lon <= lon_max & lat >= lat_min & lat <= lat_max)
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = mauritius_shape, fill = "white", color = "black") +
geom_density_2d_filled(data = data_points_filtered, aes(x = lon, y = lat), 
contour_var = "ndensity", bins = 10) +
geom_density_2d(data = data_points_filtered, aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = "black", 
size = 0.3) +
coord_sf(xlim = c(lon_min, lon_max), ylim = c(lat_min, lat_max), expand = FALSE) +
theme_minimal() +
labs(title = "Contour Map with Gradient Fill and Isolines",
   x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
annotation_scale(location = "bl", width_hint = 0.5) +
annotation_north_arrow(location = "tl", which_north = "true", style = 
north_arrow_fancy_orienteering)



If you supply a custom bin count via the bins argument, you need to supply it to both geom_density_2d and geom_density_2d_filled to make the bin contours match. P.S. Please make sure to provide reproducible examples of code.

Is this about extrapolating values outside of data_points.csv extent  to compleatly fill underlying shape?

Not sure you mean "interpolate" here, which means to find data points between other data points. Do you want to extrapolate the data outside the bounding box? And/or crop the grid to the polygon? Its unclear. Please edit and add more information.

The 'cleanest' way I know to achieve this is to create a masking layer to cover the contour data outside the extent of the island. This can be achieved using sf::st_difference(). Since you did not supply example data, here is a reprex using a SpatRaster in place of your contours.
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
library(tidyterra)

# Load island sf
mauritius <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") |>
  filter(name == "Mauritius")

# Create sample SpatRaster
lon_min <- 57.3
lon_max <- 57.8
lat_min <- -20.5
lat_max <- -19.95

# Create example SpatRaster
r <- rast(ext(lon_min + 0.05, lon_max - 0.1, 
              lat_min + 0.05, lat_max - 0.1), res = 0.01, crs = "EPSG:4326")
set.seed(1)
r[] <- sample(10, ncell(r), replace = TRUE)


# Create mask that extend()s mauritius to cover data outside extent
sf_mask <- vect(extend(ext(mauritius), .3), crs = "EPSG:4326") %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_difference(mauritius)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = mauritius, fill = "white", color = NA) +
  geom_spatraster(data = r) +
  geom_sf(data = sf_mask, fill = "white", color = "white") + 
  geom_sf(data = mauritius, fill = NA, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(lon_min, lon_max), 
           ylim = c(lat_min, lat_max),
           expand = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Contour Map with Gradient Fill and Isolines",
       x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  annotation_scale(location = "bl", width_hint = 0.5) +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "tl", which_north = "true", style = 
                           north_arrow_fancy_orienteering)


